# How to change css if specific modal is open

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a website that has several different modals which can be accessed while viewing other modals. For example you click a button it opens up a modal, then while viewing that modal you also have the option to click a button and view 9 other modals.

What I'm trying to do is detect which modal is visible and then have that button for that modal look different then the rest (underlined & bold to be specific). Similar to have navigation if you're on the home page the home tab is highlighted in the nav.

Here is the code for the modals I'm using. Edit: the first set of buttons has slightly different code than the bottom two sets, I was changing things around to try and make it work. My original code where the bottom two sets of buttons.

```
<div id="Building-Meisterhaus-Sud" style="float: left; margin:10px;  padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
  <h5 style="font-weight: bold"> Meisterhaus Nord </h5>

  <a data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" href="#floor-modal-898" data-target=""  data-dismiss="modal" role="tab" aria-label="Close"> EG </a>                                  
  <a data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-918"  data-dismiss="modal" role="tab" aria-label="Close">  1. OG </a>                                               
  <a data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-920"  data-dismiss="modal" role="tab" aria-label="Close"> 2. OG </a>

</div>


<div id="Building-Meisterhaus-Sud" style=" float: left; margin: 10px;  padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
  <h5 style="font-weight: bold"> Meisterhaus Mitte </h5>
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-921" data-dismiss="modal" > EG </a> |
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-922"  data-dismiss="modal" >  1. OG </a> |
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-923" data-dismiss="modal" > 2. OG </a>

</div>

<div id="Building-Meisterhaus-Sud" style="float: left; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
  <h5 style="font-weight: bold"> Meisterhaus Sud </h5>
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;"  data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-924" aria-label="Close"> EG </a> |
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-925" aria-label="Close"> 1. OG </a> |
  <a type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="cursor: default;" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal-926" aria-label="Close"> 2. OG </a>

</div>
```

If you notice in the picture below how Impressionen is bold and underlined because it's currently in an "active state" I want this same effect on the 9 buttons above it which display the different modals. I've tried jQuery functions but can't seem to get it to work.

[image: This is the modal with the buttons I'm trying to change highlighted]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you aspect... you want the modal closes and another one opens? Or you aspect a tab like behaviour?

Comment: @DaFois No the modals work perfectly, when you click button one closes and another opens. What I'm trying to do is have the buttons indicate which modal you are currently viewing. Similar to how a navigation tab will indicate which page you are on. If you are viewing building 2.OG then 2.OG will be in bold/underlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `show.bs.modal` event, you can retreive the id of the currently opened modal...

Assuming you wish to change the CSS on the element that triggers the modal opening **and** those are in all modals, it would be:

```
$(document).on("show.bs.modal",function(e){
  var modal_id = e.target.id;
  console.log("Modal actually opened: "+modal_id);
  $("[data-target]").removeClass("boldUnderlined");
  $("[data-target='#"+modal_id+"']").addClass("boldUnderlined");
});
```

*«I'm trying to do is detect which modal is visible»*... Now you know and you can get any of it's attribute value (like the id) to then target any other element (like the modal open link, which use a "target id" in a `data-target` attribute).

So, you can use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target the links that opens a specific modal.

Comment: So this shows me it's opening the modal for the button clicked, but is there a way to change the CSS of a particular ID if it detects the modal is open. example <a id="modal1Active"> Modal 1 </a> if modal 1 is open then it will change ID modal1Active to font-weight: bold; so if Modal 1 = True change modal1Active font-weight: bold. <---- this is just an example.

Comment: I just had a flash... Maybe you have that big 9 link "menu" in each modal... Not only in a "main" one. If so, I made another [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oMZBoQ?editors=1111) where my edit is applyed.

Comment: You are a freaking genius, this worked perfectly!!!!! Exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Great... My brain was starting to bleed a bit about what you wished to do. ;) It wasn't obvious that the 9 links where in all modals.

Comment: Lol yeah sorry, the page has a lot of other code and PHP involved was trying to trim it down some. Seriously thank you so much, I tried so many different things I'm just not very good with jQuery.

Comment: The trick here, in addition to the `show.bs.open` event, is the use of [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). ;)

Comment: If you could maybe edit your original answer to include your most recent Codepin. That was the correct one.